# Unable to interpolate on a 2D array on a meshgrid using Rectbivariatespline

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot `S` on a fine meshgrid. `S` is a 2D array with the values at points of `SR` and `Temp`. I want to make a fine meshgrid of `SR` and `Temp` and plot a contour map of `S`. I am trying to use `RectBivariateSpline`, but getting an error while finding `Z2`.

The error I am getting is:

```
in line  Z2 = zspline(TT,SR)
raise ValueError("Error code returned by bispev: %s" % ier)
ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

T = np.array([850,800,750])  
strain_rate = np.array([0.0003,0.001,0.01,0.1])  
flow_stress1 = np.array([[28.16,  49.46,  95.96],
                         [46.45,  80.51,  126.62],
                         [151.46, 107.94, 235.14], 
                         [165.63, 228.77, 319.15]])
Temp = 1000/(273+T)
TT = np. linspace(max(Temp), min(Temp),50)

S = np.log10(flow_stress1)
SR= np.log10(strain_rate)
srate= np.linspace(min(SR), max(SR),100)
zspline = RectBivariateSpline(SR,Temp,S , kx=2, ky=2)
Z2 = zspline(TT,SR)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x,y = np.meshgrid(Temp,SR)
ax.contourf(x,y,Z2)
plt.show()
```

I have tried looking but have not found a satisfactory method of solving this problem.

Comment: Googling your error message [brings up this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30086501/8881141): " ..., these need to be in strictly ascending order. " Which `TT` obviously violates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arrays into Scipy Interpolate RectBivariateSpline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083872/how-to-pass-arrays-into-scipy-interpolate-rectbivariatespline)